# Add custom Analyzer implementation through Elasticsearch plugin

Tags: java, lucene, elasticsearch

I've created an Elasticsearch plugin to index a custom datatype. I want to apply a custom analyzer at search time as well. Therefore I added the onModule method like this:

```
public class MyTypePlugin extends AbstractPlugin {

    public void onModule(AnalysisModule module) {
        module.addAnalyzer("myanalyzer", MyAnalyzerProvider.class);
    }

}
```

When I install the plugin, indexing of my custom datatype is working well. However, when I try to use my analyzer (by calling //127.0.0.1:9200/_analyze?analyzer=myanalyzer&text=this+is+a+test for example) this results in a `ElasticSearchIllegalArgumentException[failed to find analyzer [myanalyzer]]` error. Is this the right way to add a custom analyzer implementation or is there another way, like through the `FieldMapper` for example?